# Which function's power series has these coefficients of sums of inverse factorials?

Tags: power-series, binomial-coefficients, formal-power-series

I am looking for a function $f_m(x)$ described by the following power series. Its coefficients look similar to the Bell polynomials; however, my attempts to rewrite it using the Bell polynomials or the multinomial theorem did not produce meaningful results.

\begin{equation}
f_m(x) = \sum_{p=1}^{\infty} \underbrace{\frac{\sum \prod_{i=1}^p \frac{1}{k_i!}}{p+1}}_{:= a_{p,m}} x^p
\end{equation}

The sum in the numerator of the fraction is taken over all sequences of non-negative integers $k_1, \dots, k_p$ which fulfill

\begin{align}
p &= \sum_{i=1}^p i \cdot k_i \\
m &= \sum_{i=1}^p k_i \qquad m \in \mathbb{N}, m \geq 1
\end{align}

My question: Is $f_m(x)$ an already well-known and studied function or a composition of such functions?

**EDIT**

I just found that the coefficient of the power series, $a_{p,m}$, is zero for $m > p$. In addition, it appears that the numerator can be rewritten as
\begin{align}
\sum \prod_{i=1}^p \frac{1}{k_i!} = \frac{(p-1)!}{(p-m)!(m-1)!m!}
\end{align}

Hence, $f_m(x)$ can be restated:
\begin{align}
f_m(x) &= \sum_{p=m}^{\infty} \frac{(p-1)!}{(p-m)!(m-1)!m!(p+1)} x^p\\
&= x^m \sum_{p=0}^{\infty} \frac{(p+m-1)!}{p!(m-1)!m!(p+m+1)} x^p\\
&= \frac{1}{x} \frac{x^{m+1}}{m!} \sum_{p=0}^{\infty} \binom{p+m-1}{m-1}\frac{1}{p+m+1} x^p\\
&= \frac{1}{x} \int dx \,\frac{x^{m}}{m!} \underbrace{\sum_{p=0}^{\infty} \binom{p+m-1}{m-1} x^p}_{= (1-x)^{-m}}\\
&= \frac{1}{x} \int dx \,\frac{1}{m!} \left(\frac{x}{1-x}\right)^m\\
&= \frac{x^m}{(m+1)!} \, {_2}F_1(m,m+1;m+2,x)
\end{align}
Thanks to [TravorLZH](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/748964/travorlzh) for pointing out the steps in the last two lines.

Comment: Look up [generalized hypergeometric function](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/GeneralizedHypergeometricFunction.html)

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick!